# Where to download phonetic word list for English

Tags: phonetics, ipa, dictionary

I need phonetic word lists / dictionaries for English.
I did not assume that this would be hard to find online. 
What do you use?
What is available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For English, the [CMU dictionary](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict) is the must usual source. You do have to convert the text to IPA letters in some font because it uses ARPAbet, but it is a straightforward process.